# File Parsing problem

Tags: python

I have a question about my homework problem. Here is the problem: 
Write a program which reads a text file called input.txt which contains an arbitrary number of lines of the form ", " then records this information using a dictionary, and finally outputs to the screen a list of countries represented in the file and the number of cities contained.

For example, if input.txt contained the following:

New York, US
Angers, France
Los Angeles, US
Pau, France
Dunkerque, France
Mecca, Saudi Arabia

The program would output the following (in some order):

Saudi Arabia : 1
US : 2
France : 3

Here is my Code:

```
def addword(w,wcDict):
    if w in wcDict:
        wcDict[w] +=1
    else:
        wcDict[w]= 1

import string
def processLine(line, wcDict):
    wordlist= line.strip().split(",")
    for word in wordlist:
        word= word.lower().strip()
        word=word.strip(string.punctuation)
        addword(wordlist[1], wcDict)

def prettyprint(wcDict):
    valkeylist= [(val,key) for key,val in wcDict.items()]
    valkeylist.sort(reverse = True)
    for val,key in valkeylist:
        print '%-12s    %3d'%(key,val)

def main():
    wcDict={}
    fobj= open('prob1.txt','r')
    for line in fobj:
        processLine(line, wcDict)
    prettyprint (wcDict)

 main()
```

My code counts each country twice. Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Here's a hint: look at your call to `addword` in the `processLine` function.

Comment: Yes i know that this is where my problem is but i can't figure out why it counts it twice.

Comment: Look at what you're adding. You go through all the trouble to prepare a variable called `word`, but what are you actually passing to the function?

Comment: minor nitpick, but common issue (unrelated to your question) and one i do too.... don't forget to close the file or use the `with` keyword to have it close it for you. assuming this is all the source for the project.

Comment: Perhaps Sarah can help you? She was doing this homework last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606127/python-file-parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `processLine` function, you have an extraneous for loop.  `wordlist` will always contain two entries, the city and the country.  So the code inside your for loop (including `addword`) will be executed twice -- you can just delete the `for` statement entirely and it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter as c
lines = (line.strip() for line in open("file.txt"))
data = (elem for elem in lines)
result = [two for one in data for two in one.split(",")]
c = Counter()
c(result)
```

I hope i answered your query

Comment: {' France': 3,
         ' Saudi Arabia': 1,
         ' US': 2,
         'Angers': 1,
         'Dunkerque': 1,
         'Los Angeles': 1,
         'Mecca': 1,
         'New York': 1,
         'Pau': 1}
This was my result..